# Getting Last Windows Update in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am looking to write a single string to a UI displaying the last time a Windows Update was applied using powershell.

I am currently using the command
`$LastInstallDate = (Get-HotFix | Sort-Object -Property InstalledOn)[-1] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'InstalledOn'`

However this returns errors on random machines I try it on

```
Exception getting "InstalledOn": "Exception calling "Parse" with "2" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.""
```

When this does work occasionally, it also shows the time at 00:00:00, I would like to axe this off the output if possible so I just get the date.

TIA

Comment: The error is telling you that `InstalledOn` is not in a valid date format - it's either completely wrong (i.e. not any common date format) or possibly a language issue, for example your system uses 'month-day-year', but the date is stored as 'day-month-year'.  I'd suggest looking at the direct output of `Get-Hotfix` to see if you can identify what's actually going on, then an appropriate solution can be applied.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$LastInstallDate = Get-HotFix | Sort-Object -Property InstalledOn | Select-Object -Last 1 -Property @{l='InstalledDate';e={$_.InstalledOn.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")
Write-Host "The last installed update or hotfix was installed on $($LastInstallDate.InstalledDate)"
```

Alternatively

```
$LastInstallDate = Get-HotFix | Sort-Object -Property InstalledOn | Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty InstalledOn
Write-Host "The last installed update or hotfix was installed on $($LastInstallDate.ToString('dd MMMM yyyy'))"
```

I prefer the latter as it's a DateTime variable that's assigned rather than a PSObject containing the string version of the date.

Comment: How do I parse that to a variable ? $LastInstallDate = Get-HotFix | Sort-Object -Property InstalledOn | Select-Object -Property @{l='InstalledDate';e={$_.InstalledON.ToString('dd MMM yyyy')}}

Write-Host "The last installed update or hotfix was installed on $LastInstallDate"                                     It is currently just displaying blank when trying to write variable to host.

Comment: @CallumStones I've just updated my answer to also include a better alternative and to use the Select-Object -Last parameter to take the last item in the date-sorted list of hot-fixes.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want:

```
#Gets log entries about all successfully installed patches
$successUpdatesInstalls = Get-WinEvent -ProviderName 'Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient' -FilterXPath "*[System[EventID=19]]"

#Pick the latest one and output datetime
$successUpdatesInstalls[0].TimeCreated
```